# Некорректное отображение bitmap в LargeIcon Notification, Android

Tags: android, android-notification

```
public void showNotification(){
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder (getApplicationContext());
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ImageActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    builder
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getCacheDir() + "/Image-" + 1 + ".jpg"))
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("напоминание")
            .setContentText("Напоминание!");
    Notification notification = builder.build();
    int NOTIFICATION = 127;
    nm.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
}
```

`LargeImage` не инициализируется, а просто вместо нее ставится `SmallIcon`. Вернее сказать эту строку код не хочет воспринимать. Если задавать картинку изначально в `drawable` ресурсах, получается нормально, но если мне ее надо скачать, ничего не выходит

Comment: вы уверены, что все правильно? например, путь к изображению?

Comment: да уверен, путь задан корректно, в других частях программы открывается, возможно так же из-за того что notification в сервисе, хотя не думаю что это большая проблема

Comment: а в `LogCat` есть что-нибудь в момент показа `notification`'а?

Comment: спасибо большое и чтение файла осуществлялось пока он загрузился,  wait() исправило проблему.

Comment: @user199598, если вы нашли решение проблемы, то можете написать о нём в ответе.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
FileInputStream stream1=new FileInputStream(new File(getCacheDir() + "/Image-" + 1 + ".jpg"));
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1,null,o);
stream1.close();

//далее
//.setLargeIcon(bm)
```